# Input string with format into a bash command

Tags: linux, bash

I would like to hard code some inputs to my bash script command. For example, I have a bash script like this:

```
#! /bin/bash
apt-get install python
```

and I would like to hard code `y` and `enter` as the input for the `apt-get` command in this bash script, as sometime user might b asked to confirm the space of the installation. I know I can do

```
apt-get install python <<< 'y'
```

to pass a string input `y`, but can I also input special format, like the newline '\n' using this method? Thanks!

Comment: In general, scripting simulated end-user input is extremely fragile. Since programs are designed to have such input provided by a human who can read and follow directions (rather than a script that blindly does the same thing each time), there generally aren't taken to be compatibility constraints that prevent the required input from changing in arbitrary ways between releases or based on conditions observed at runtime.

Comment: ...by contrast, if you can find and use a programmatic interface for specifying configuration, those interfaces are far more likely to be subject to forwards-compatibility guarantees.

Comment: Thank you @CharlesDuffy for all your suggestions, they are very helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All herestrings automatically are terminated by a newline, so this may not do what you want. (Many programs look at whether their input is coming from a TTY, and change whether and how they prompt based on the result; others read prompts intended to come from a user *directly* from a TTY, and so bypass piped contents, heredocs, and herestrings entirely).

That said, for a literal answer to the question:

```
apt-get install python <<<$'y\n'
```

You can also use a heredoc:

```
apt-get install python <<EOF
y

EOF
```

---

That said, for the specific case of `apt-get`, don't do that!

```
apt-get install -y python
```

...is indeed the best practice. (And for system administration commands in general, batch or automated use is generally anticipated by their developers, so end-user input is rarely required -- look in each program's documentation for arguments such as `--batch`, `--force`, `--always` or `--yes`; environment variables that specify items that otherwise would be prompted for; or behaviors activated by having stdin not be a TTY).

Answer (score 2):

`apt-get -y install python` is the correct way.  According to the manpage:

> **-y, --yes, --assume-yes**
>   Automatic yes to prompts; assume "yes" as answer to all prompts and run non-interactively. If an undesirable situation, such as changing a held package, trying to install a unauthenticated package or removing an
>              essential package occurs then apt-get will abort. Configuration Item: APT::Get::Assume-Yes.

Comment: I'm assuming that apt-get is just a stand-in example and that the OP wants something generic enough to work with "a bash command". If it's legitimately the object of their question, then this is absolutely The Right Thing.

Comment: Yeah, I agree I didn't really answer the question.  Instead I treated it as the XY problem.